# PHP errors relating to matrix on channel form submission

Tags: matrix, safecracker, pixelandtonic

EE 2.9.0
Matrix 2.6

I have a template with a channel form in it, nothing else (I've stripped it down for testing).

```
{exp:channel:form
    channel="test_channel_form"
    return="test-return"
    }    
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="{title}" onkeyup="liveUrlTitle();">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
{/exp:channel:form}
```

This is using a test channel field group with no custom fields.
It returns to the correct page on submission and an entry is created.

Changing the channel to use another field group I run into problems.
The field group has 5 fields, 2 textarea fields and 3 Matrix fields. I only need the text area fields in this channel form.

My template code is

```
{exp:channel:form
    channel="test_channel_form"
    return="test-return"
    }    
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="{title}" onkeyup="liveUrlTitle();">
    {field:news_summary}
    {field:news_body}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
{/exp:channel:form}
```

An entry is created OK but it doesn't return to the specified page on submission it just stays on the same page and I get the following errors.

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
Filename: matrix/ft.matrix.php
Line Number: 2259

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: matrix/ft.matrix.php
Line Number: 2259

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
Filename: matrix/ft.matrix.php
Line Number: 2259

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: matrix/ft.matrix.php
Line Number: 2259

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
Filename: matrix/ft.matrix.php
Line Number: 2259

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: matrix/ft.matrix.php
Line Number: 2259

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/timprint/Dropbox/Sites/imagineering/imageesys47836/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
Filename: libraries/Functions.php
Line Number: 446

Comment: So you're not actually using any Matrix fields in the Channel Form?

Comment: No. But still getting Matrix errors. I initially thought they may be set as required fields but they aren't.

Comment: Adding a me too to this. No Matrix fields on the Channel Form, but there is on the Channel Field group assigned to the entry.

Comment: +1 same situation of Brendan

Comment: Hey guys, Stack Exchange isn’t really the best place to report/support software bugs. If you’re experiencing this error, please get in touch via support@pixelandtonic.com so we can look into this.

Comment: I've got around this by including the matrix field in the channel form and hiding it on the front-end. Not ideal but I was under pressure to get something working. I've sent a support request outlining the exact issue for reference @BrandonKelly

Answer (score -1):

I'm adding my name to this list of having the same problem, although for me I DO have a matrix field in my public facing channel form.

EE 2.9.0 / Matrix 2.6